# Cannot produce to Kafka from Python code

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I have this modules running(all local):

- ZooKeeper
- Kafka Server
- Kafka Consumer
- Python script

In the script there's a `send()` call:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
producer.send('test', 'entry1')
```

every 15 seconds or so. 
Almost every `send()` call yields on The Kafka Server these errors:

```
[2017-10-16 18:59:10,953] ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka.common.KafkaException: Wrong request type 16
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.deserializerForKey(RequestKeys.scala:64)
at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-10-16 18:59:11,158] INFO Closing socket connection to /127.0.0.1. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2017-10-16 18:59:11,162] INFO Closing socket connection to /127.0.0.1. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2017-10-16 18:59:11,162] ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka.common.KafkaException: Wrong request type 18
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.deserializerForKey(RequestKeys.scala:64)
at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It's an almost, because every 5 minuets(more or less) the entry does get to the consumer right, but then the errors return.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Which Kafka client are you using, and which version of Kafka? Did you try this one? https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python